# Reading Text files and inserting the words present in those files into a table in sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server-2008

I have a folder that  contains 25000 text files and i would like to read these files and place the words into table.My text files are named in the following format 1.txt,2.txt,........and so on to 25000.txt. Each text file contains words in the following form.

```
sample contents of my file
apple
cat
rat
shoe
```

The words may be repeated in other textfiles too, i want a c# code that could read  the text files identify the words that are repeated and also those that are not repeated and then insert them into database in Sqlserver in the following form.

```
keyword    document name
cat        1.txt,2.txt,3.txt
rat        4.txt,1.txt
fish       5.txt
```

`

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.ComponentModel;

using System.Data;

using System.Drawing;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;


using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.IO;

using System.Data.SqlClient;



namespace RAMESH
 {
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text, "*.txt");
        int i;
        string sqlstmt,str;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=dell-pc\\sql1; initial         catalog=db; user id=sa; password=a;");
        SqlCommand cmd;
        sqlstmt = "delete from Items";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlstmt, con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        for (i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(files[i]);
            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(files[i]);
            string fname;
            fname = f.Name;
            fname = fname.Substring(0, fname.LastIndexOf('.'));
            //MessageBox.Show(fname);
            while ((str = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                int nstr=1;
                //int x,y;
                //for (x = 0; x < str.Length; x++)
                //{ 
                //    y = Convert.ToInt32(str.Substring(x,1));
                //    if ((y < 48 && y > 75) || (y < 65 && y > 97) || (y < 97 && y > 122)) ;
                //}
                sqlstmt = "insert into Items values('" + str + "','" + fname + "')";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlstmt, con);                    
                try
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    sqlstmt = "update Items set docname=docname + '," + fname + "'   where itemname='" + str + "'";
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlstmt, con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            sr.Close();
        }
        MessageBox.Show("keywords added successfully");
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

}
`

Comment: What have you tried thus far?   Show us what you have done on your own, ask specific questions and you'll get specific answers.

Comment: ok im sending my c#code

Comment: Can you add a stored procedure to your database? This code is very inefficient and prone to numerous problems like Sql Injections

Comment: *I want them...in the following form...*: no, you don't. You don't want to store the files as a single column with a comma-delimited list. You want to store them in a normalised form, so you can sensibly query them, and make comma-delimited versions out of the normalised values in a separate query ONLY when someone insists on it and makes threats of violence.

Comment: Right now you are inserting a whole line.  Define how you want to parse.  And you really want the C# program to parse all the files and determine repeated words and THEN insert.

Comment: See i want to parse all the files and then find words that are repeated and those that appear only once and the corresponding document names in which they appear

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost I will add a Stored procedure to your database to isolate the logic for update or insert

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpsertWords
@word nvarchar(MAX), @file nvarchar(256)
as

    Declare @cnt integer
    Select @cnt = Count(*) from Items where ItemName = @word
    if @cnt = 0 
        INSERT INTO Items (@word, @file)
    else
        UPDATE Items SET docname = docname + ',' + @file where ItemName = @word
```

Now, we could simplify your code a lot

```
.....

// Build the command just one time, outside the loop,
// make it point to the stored procedure above
cmd = new SqlCommand("UpsertWords", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                    

// Create dummy parameters, the actual value is supplied inside the loop
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@word", string.Empty);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@file", string.Empty);

// Now loop on every file
for (i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
{
    // Open and read all the lines in the current file
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(files[i]);

    // Get only the filename part without the extension
    string fname = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files[i])

    // In case of just one line per file, this loop will execute just one time
    // however we also could handle more than one line per file
    foreach(string line in lines)
    {
        // Set the actual value of the parameters created outside the loop
        cmd.Parameters["@word"] = line;
        cmd.Parameters["@file"] = fname;
        // Run the insert or update (the logic is inside the storedprocedure)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

At this point is not clear if your line is composed of a single word or if you have more than one word separated by some character (tab, comma, semicolon). In that case you need to split the string and another loop.

However, I find your database schema wrong. It is better to add a new row  for every word with the file in which it appears. In this way a simple query like

```
SELECT  docname from Items where itemname = @word
```

will yeld all the files without any big performance problem and you have a more searchable database.
Or, if you need to count the occurence of a word

```
SELECT ItemName, COUNT(ItemName) as WordCount 
FROM Items 
GROUP BY ItemName 
ORDER BY Count(ItemName) ASC
```

Comment: can you explain this procedure briefly my text file consists only one word in one line

Comment: For the second option you don't need to change the format of the table, just be sure to not have an unique index on the ItemName field. (Of course the stored procedure should change accordingly)

Comment: This method is very inefficient, with 25000 files, assuming 10 lines per file, your method would cause 250k selects, inserts and/or updates.

Comment: Alternative approached provided below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

First start with your Files, loop through and create a simple XML document.

```
        var fname = "File12.txt";
        var keywords = new List<string>(new[]{ "dog", "cat", "moose" });           

        var miXML = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"), new XElement("root"));

        foreach (var el in keywords.Select(i => new XElement("item", new XAttribute("key", i))))
        {
            miXML.Root.Add(el);
        }

        using (var con = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=HT;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("uspUpsert", con) {CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure})
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@X", miXML.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileName", fname);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Then for your stored procedure you can call this Proc, which will convert that XML into a table, inserting the keywords and the file name into the database.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspUpsert
    @X xml,
    @Filename varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    WITH KV as (
        select 
            x.v.value('@key', 'varchar(20)') as Keyword
            ,@FileName as FileName
        FROM   @x.nodes('/root/item') x(v) 
    )
    insert into Items 
    select KV.keyWord, KV.FileName
    from KV
    left outer join Items I on I.Keyword=KV.Keyword and I.FileName=KV.FileName
    where I.id is null
END
```

Since you likely don't want 'file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt' to find duplicates, you will use this query to find words in duplicate files:

```
select * from items where keyword='dog'
```

Alternatively, could now take a count and do all other aggregation on this table as well.